# Setting Colors in SWT

Tags: java, swt, colors

This is pretty simple, I come from a swing/awt background.

I'm just wondering what the proper way to set the background color for a SWT widget is?

I've been trying:

```
widget.setBackground( );
```

Except I have no idea how to create the color Object in SWT?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

To create a color, try this:

```
Device device = Display.getCurrent ();
Color red = new Color (device, 255, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Make sure you don't forget to dispose of this Color!  Otherwise you will leak native resources.

Answer (score 91):

For standard colors (including common colors and default colors used by the operating system) Use `Display.getSystemColor(int)`, and pass in the `SWT.COLOR_*` constant for the color you want.

```
Display display = Display.getCurrent();
Color blue = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE);
Color listBackground = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_LIST_BACKGROUND);
```

Note that you do not need to dispose these colors because SWT created them.

Comment: This should be your standard for any color supported in the SWT.COLOR_* set.  As stated, you do not need to remember to dispose of colors created in this fashion.

Comment: `SWT.COLOR_LIST_BACKGROUND` : awesome.

Answer (score 11):

Remember that in SWT you must explicitly dispose any resources that you create when you are done with them.  This includes widgets, fonts, colors, images, displays, printers, and GCs.  If you do not dispose these resources, eventually your application will reach the resource limit of your operating system and the application will cease to run.

See also: [SWT: Managing Operating System Resources](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/swt-design-2/swt-design-2.html)

Comment: I suggest you use this [SWTResourceManager](https://www.eclipse.org/ecf/org.eclipse.ecf.docs/api/org/eclipse/ecf/ui/SWTResourceManager.html)