# how to change colour of label in swt tree editor

Tags: java, tree, editor, swt

I have a TreeEditor and some text in its first column.  I need to append some text to it using a label or string.  In addition, I want to change the color of the appended string to green.  I tried to do it with this code, but it isn't working:

```
Label label = new Label(this.tree ,SWT.RIGHT);
label.setFont(new Font(getSite().getShell().getDisplay(), ("Hello"), 18,
        SWT.BOLD));
label.setText("hello:));
label.pack();
treeItem.setText(1, hi + "        " + label.getText());
```

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Setting color in swt see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50064/setting-colors-in-swt

Comment: By the way, there's an error in the code posted; there is no closing quote in the string for "hello:" at line 3.

Comment: Do you want to have the TreeItem's text in *two* different colors? I do not see any simple solution. One way would be to use two columns. Consider JFace and ColumnLabelProvider in this case. Otherwise try embedding your own custom control into the tree.

Answer (score 2):

you might want to look at  `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider`